# Android - Google Maps - Camera Update every location change

Tags: android, maps

I'm building an app, which has to keep the user in the center of the map all the time.

I have set up the following:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) saveContext
        .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locationListener = new MapLocationListener();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000,
        10, locationListener);
if (myLocation != null) {
    setLocation(myLocation);
}

private void setLocation(Location location) {
    workoutMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
            location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 18.0f));
}
```

This works, as  long I have a lastKnownLocation in my phone's history. The map will center correctly.

I wish that every time I'm getting a new location update, setLocation() will be executed again, with the new location info.

I've tried creating a thread which just does get the lastKnownLocation and then setLocation();
But this isn't working out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the excellent and complete sample at Googles [Receiving Location Updates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) guide.

It includes sample code and an Android project you can import in ADT straight away.

The callback method that Location Services invokes to send a location update to your app is specified in the LocationListener interface, in the method onLocationChanged().

There you can put your camera update.

Comment: I don't see any project at that link.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else stumbles on this, it can be done and the answer, given by user Rob, is in another StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074129/google-maps-v2-set-both-my-location-and-zoom-in).

The basic idea is to create a CameraPosition object, pass this to the CameraUpdateFactory and then have the map animate the CameraUpdate object.