# Prevent map from changing center location on zoom. android SDK

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to recreate a "drag the map to set your location"(like Uber and Lyft) feature in my app.
my Idea is to adding a marker/pin icon on top of the map interface, setting that pin to the center, and finally use `map.getCameraPosition();` to find the lat long of the pin. But the major UX issue I am facing is when I zoom(double tap or pinch zoom)  on the map. By default it will zoom and drag the map to the location of my fingers. How to disable that. I have attached my screenshots bellow.
[image: Before Zoom]

[image: After Zoom]

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: See: [campera update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074129/google-maps-v2-set-both-my-location-and-zoom-in)

Comment: @EvgenyMaltsev I am facing problem when user manually zooms in. double tap or pinch zoom.

Comment: @Bedant hey, do you success to do what you want ?

Comment: @agonist_ I somehow managed to override the double tap function but It does not work with pinch zoom